# What is the very last event fired off during creation of a silverlight page

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, event-handling

I know this may seem like an odd question, but I am after the information queried in the title.
So far I have tried LayoutRoot.Loaded, but found that LayoutRoot.LayoutUpdated happens even later.

My motivation for this knowledge is the ability to have one component interact with another in code, but for this to happen I must be guaranteed they both exist.

Any ideas?

---

Clarification of what I'm attempting to do:
I have a collapsing gridsplitter control. [From here](http://shemesh.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/silverlight-gridsplitter-with-a-collapse%C2%A0button-%E2%80%93-best/)
When the main page loads I make it collapse; which shrinks the object preceding it to width 0. If that object isn't 'loaded' yet then it doesn't collapse and the gridsplitter is in an odd state where it thinks it has collapsed the item but needs two clicks to effectively do that.

Comment: -1..Exactly..very odd question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LayoutUpdated` is the last event raised in the control object initialization timeline. However keep in mind that LayoutUpdated will be raised multiple time subsequently as required. Maybe you can share a little more detail on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was related to timing in a display animation. What I think happened was the animation didn't have time to finish so it's resulting effect didn't take hold. Your answer is correct, but I couldn't use it to fix my bug. In the end I averted the issue by disabling animation for this specific instance of collapse.